# Series $\sum \frac{1}{n^2\sin^3n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

**Question** : Show that series $\sum \cfrac{1}{n^{2}\sin^{3}n}$ is divergent.

**Hint:**

Show that $$\sum \frac{1}{n|\sin(n)|}$$ is divergent.

> I am interested in other possible proofs for this question.

Comment: The divergence of the first series is actually open, if I recall correctly.

Comment: $\sum \frac{1}{n^3sin^{2}(n)}$ is open

Comment: Ah, there you go. Well, have you tried anything? It seems you're not new to this...

Comment: I found a solution, but I'd like to see another solution.

Comment: Well, be explicit about that in your post. Post your solution, and say "I want to look at other possible proofs" or something of the sort.

Comment: The way I'd think of doing it is to use that abs(sin) values on the integers are dense in $[0,1]$ and find a suitable subseqence that will dominate the $n^2$ denominator

Answer (score 4):

Since $\pi$ is irrational, by [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28number_theory%29), there are infinitely many pairs of relative prime integers $(n,m)$ such that

$$\left|\pi - \frac{n}{m}\right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}{m^2}}
\quad\implies\quad|n - m\pi| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}m}
$$
We can assume both $n, m > 0$ and for any such pair, we have
$$
|\sin n | = |\sin(n-m\pi)| < \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}m} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}m}
= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}n}\left( \pi + ( \frac{n}{m} - \pi )\right)
< \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}n}\left( \pi + 1\right)
\\ \implies \frac{1}{n^2 |\sin n|^3} > \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\pi+1}\right)^3 n$$
This means the sequence $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{n^2\sin^{3}n}\;$ doesn't converge to $0$
and hence the series diverges.